# How to use VS Code Hover Provider Text Color?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, hover

Heyyy,

Is there any possibility to use any sort of color in the Hover Provider?

[image]

Like this:

[image]

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, did it with the language property. Now it's highlighted like the language itself.

```
var hoverContent = {
    contents: [{ language: 'al', value: `${message.Name}: ${message.Type} "${message.Type2}"` }]
};
```